# How do I tail all files and exclude some files by wildcard name?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tail

I would like to tail all of the files in directory with the exception of files that include a certain string in their filename. Also, I want to highlight certain words that are included within the files as the command is running.

This is for CentOS specifically regarding tailing all of the domlogs or httpd access logs.

While these work directly via bash, they don't work when included in a script.

When added to a script I also add #!/bin/bash before the following code snippet.

This is the command I am using:

```
!#/bin/bash

export GREP_COLOR='1;37;41'

tail -f /var/log/apache2/domlogs/!(*bytes*) | grep --color=auto -E '(^|Ubuntu|xmlrpc|spider|spider|python|crawler|Crawler|wp-login|wp-admin|zoom)'
```

This fails and throws an error when it hit's the first (.

I am expecting it to go ahead and display all of the domlogs with highlighted text.

Comment: `!#` should be `#!`

Comment: Make sure you enable extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: Ah..yes. I fat-fingered that. It is !#. Sorry.

Comment: Barmar, that worked. I added your solution just after #!/bin/bash and it's working properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended wildcards are not enabled by default, you need to use `shopt` to enable them.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
export GREP_COLOR='1;37;41'

tail -f /var/log/apache2/domlogs/!(*bytes*) | grep --color=auto -E '(^|Ubuntu|xmlrpc|spider|spider|python|crawler|Crawler|wp-login|wp-admin|zoom)'
```